# problem to add access to RSA key container

Tags: .net

I have two administrator users on my machine. With the first one I am creating a machine level key:

aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" -exp

and I see it created in "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys".

Now I am trying to add access privileges with the second one:

"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe" -pa NetFrameworkConfigurationKey "XXX"
Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container...
The RSA key container was not found.
Failed!

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues. Make sure you are opening the command window as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The aspnet_regiis tool is not very robust around key containers. Once it gets itself in a corrupted state, there's nothing it can do to help you.

Just delete that key file manually through explorer.

Then you should be able to use aspnet_regiis to re-add it and manage ACLs.